# Matlab load mat into variable

Tags: matlab, load

When loading data from a .Mat file directly into a variable, it stores an struct instead of the variable itself.

Example:

`myData.mat`  contains `var1`, `var2`, `var3`

if I do:

```
load myData.mat
```

it will create the variables var1, var2 and var3 in my workspace. OK.

If I assign what `load` returns to a variable, it stores an struct. This is normal since I'm loading several variables.

```
foo = load('myData.mat')

foo = 
  struct with fields:
    var1
    var2
    var3
```

However suppose that I'm only interested in `var1` and I want to directly store into a variable `foo`.

Load has an option of loading only specific variables from a .mat file, however it still stores an struct

```
foo = load('myData.mat', 'var1')
foo = 
      struct with fields:
        var1
```

I want `var1` to be directly assigned to `foo`.

Of course I can do:

```
foo = load('myData.mat', 'var1')
foo = foo.var1;
```

But it should be a way of doing this automatically in one line right?

Comment: What bothers you? `clear var1`? In that case, you can use: `foo=load('myData.mat', 'var1')`
`foo=foo.var1;`

Comment: What it bothers me is that I cannot directly load the variable that I want and have to reassign foo to foo.var1. Will update the question with your proposal, which is nicer than using clear. Matlab should have a special case when you load only one variable so it doesn't load the struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`load` does not behave this way otherwise `load` would behave inconsistently depending upon the number of variables that you have requested which would lead to an *extremely* confusing behavior.

To illustrate this, imagine that you wrote a general program that wanted to load all variables from a .mat file, make some modification to them, and then save them again. You want this program to work with *any* file so some files may have one variable and some may have multiple variables stored in them.

If `load` used the behavior you've specified, then you'd have to add in all sorts of logic to check how many variables were stored in a file before loading and modifying it.

Here is what this program would look like with the current behavior of `load`

```
function modifymyfile(filename)
    data = load(filename);

    fields = fieldnames(data);

    for k = 1:numel(fields)
        data.(fields{k}) = modify(data.(fields{k}));
    end

    save(filename, '-struct', 'data')
end
```

If the behavior was the way that you think you want

```
function modifymyfile(filename)

    % Use a matfile to determine the number of variables
    vars = whos(matfile(filename));

    % If there is only one variable
    if numel(vars) == 1
        % Assign that variable (have to use eval)
        tmp = load(filename, vars(1).name);
        tmp = modify(tmp);

        % Now to save it again, you have to use eval to reassign
        eval([vars(1).name, '= tmp;']);

        % Now resave
        save(filename, vars(1).name);
    else
        data = load(filename);

        fields = fieldnames(data);

        for k = 1:numel(fields)
            data.(fields{k}) = modify(data.(fields{k}));
        end

        save(filename, '-struct', 'data');
    end
end
```

I'll leave it to the reader to decide which of these is more legible and robust.

The best way to do what you're trying to do is exactly what you've shown in your question. Simply reassign the value after loading

```
data = load('myfile.mat', 'var1');
data = data.var1;
```

**Update**

Even if you only wanted the variable to not be assigned to a `struct` when a variable was explicitly specified, you'd still end up with inconsistent behavior which would make it difficult if my program accepted a list of variables to change as a cell array

```
variables = {'var1', 'var2'}

data = load(filename, variables{:});    % Would yield a struct

variables = {'var1'};

data = load(filename, variables{:});    % Would not yield a struct
```

Comment: I think if you just call load without specifying which variables to load, then a struct has to be returned even if the mat file has only one variable. BUT, if you explicitly pass a list of variables and you only pass one, then I would consider acceptable to load directly the variable. Or make load accept a flag to get through the struct directly to the variable.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki The first example would still yield inconsistent behavior. A flag would be a better approach but it's really adds unnecessary complication to `load` since you can really do the same thing in your calling function in a single line of code.

Answer (score 3):

If the MAT-file contains one variable, use

```
x = importdata(mat_file_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

@Suever is right, but in case you wish for a one-line workaround this will do it:

```
foo = getfield(load('myData.mat'), 'var1');
```

Comment: Since R2020a it is possible to do `foo = load(...).var1`. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/indexing-into-function-call-results.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks ugly but does what you want:

```
foo = subsref(matfile('myData.mat'),struct('type','.','subs','var1'))
```

Use `matfile` allows partial loading of variables into memory i.e. it only loads what is necessary. The function `subsref` does the job of the indexing operator "." in this case.

Comment: Note: to use `matfile` you must save your .mat file using v7.3 compression: `save('myData.mat','var1','var2','-v7.3')`